# Create and loop through raster models in python

Tags: python, arrays

Hey I am at the beginning of my work with Python for my Masters Thesis and currently stuck while dealing with the following task:

I want to create a 2D raster model with columns and rows ranging from e.g. -100 to 100 (0 in the centre). I thought about multidimensional arrays or "normal" lists!?

After having this model, the goal is to loop (two for-loops?) through the raster and to write all positions (combinations of col and row values) into a txt file.

Desired result:

row   col

-100 -100

-100 -99

-100 -98

........

1. How can I create a 200x200 raster model?
2. How can I write all possible coordinate combinations to a list/ text file?
3. Probably it is enough to just create two lists containing values from -x to x and calculate the permutations into a list/file?

Thx for any ideas!!

Comment: What is your question..?

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a two dimentional array ranging from 0 to 200, and subtract 100 when printing